# Instagram followers count

Tags: json, instagram

For few days ago page `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1` returns 403 error. Is there another easy way to get account followers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was one of the undocumented endpoints it has to be stopped at some point because it was not supposed to be accessible to public. It is really recommend to not to use these undocumented endpoints in your app instead use Instagram API.

However You can get edge_followed_by using this php solution, I haven't tested it but you can try :-

```
$name = "{username}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.instagram.com/$name/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if($http=="200") {
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($result);
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $js = $xpath->query('//body/script[@type="text/javascript"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $start = strpos($js, '{');
  $end = strrpos($js, ';');
  $json = substr($js, $start, $end - $start);
  $data = json_decode($json, true);
  $user_id = $data["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"]["edge_followed_by"]["count"];
}
```

Comment: works fine, thanks. Just need to add ['count'] at end of arrays.

Comment: @Duna Glad that it worked. Thank You for informing about last object. I've updated my question.

Comment: Well, this is still an undocumented way to get the information. What if they change the markup ?