# Problems with Instagram API on followers count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, instagram-api

I am currently running a script to have a live count of followers but it randomly stops working for a while and when I refresh the page, the number drops to 0 until I refresh it again randomly. Not sure what I am doing wrong, is there maybe a way to get the count of followers without going through an API?

EDIT: Actually found out why. The script is making too many requests so it passes the limits set by IG, is there another way to pull the amount of followers? Or limit the requests sent by the script?

Here is the code I use to pull the number from the API

```js
var myCounter = new flipCounter('flip-counter', {value:0,auto:false});
var token = 'ACCESS_TOKEN';
var ref = false;
var tt;
function refs(){
$.ajax({

url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self',

dataType: 'jsonp',

type: 'GET',

data: {access_token: token},

success: function(data){

var follows = data['data']['counts']['followed_by'];
if(!ref){
myCounter.incrementTo(follows, 3, 100);
ref=true;
}else{
myCounter.setValue(follows);
}
clearTimeout(tt);
tt=setTimeout(function(){
 refs();
},3000);
},

error: function(data){

console.log(data);

}

});
}
refs();
</script>
```

Comment: Need the error message to debug, you are most likely hitting rate limits

Comment: Yeah figured that out after. Could you or someone help me implement this PHP code to pull the number instead of API? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828694/instagram-followers-count

I tried but couldn't make it work

Comment: I strongly advise against implementing scraping here, instead - please read the documentation and implement your calls correctly to take rate limiting into account. See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview/#rate-limiting